# Flutter - How to align NavigationRail labels to the left?

Tags: flutter, alignment, uinavigationbar, leftalign

I have a very simple NavigationRail, and I was testing with different font sizes with selected and unselected labels. When both keep an equal font size, there are no problems with alignment, but if I give a larger value to the selected labels, or if I put a longer text, the others align to the center apparently. Is there a way to control this behavior, to align either all together, or separately?

[image: Screenshot]

This is my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: tituloAppBar,
        backgroundColor: colorBackground,
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: changeDestination,
            extended: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 850,
            unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: Text('Buscar Talleres y Extracurriculares'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.engineering),
                label: Text('Ingeniería y Agronomía'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: Text('Sociales y Administración'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital),
                label: Text('Salud'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                label: Text('Iniciales'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.design_services),
                label: Text('Talleres y Extracurriculares'),
              ),
            ],
            selectedLabelTextStyle:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontSize: 20),
            unselectedLabelTextStyle: 
                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
            groupAlignment: -1,
            minWidth: 56,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I tried to change the padding, the textAlign field to each Widget Text. I tried wrapping in other Widgets to set padding or margin, but nothing worked.

Comment: If you see the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/navigation_rail.dart#L442), in line 442, it uses `Column` and does not have its `crossAxisAlignment` set, which defaults to `CrossAxisAlignment.center`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You just need to wrap NavigationRail with flexible and it will work just as needed like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb99F.png)

This is code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: tituloAppBar,
    backgroundColor: colorBackground,
  ),
  body: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: NavigationRail(
          selectedIndex: _counter,
          onDestinationSelected: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _counter = value;
            });
          },
          extended: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 850,
          unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
          destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: Text('Buscar Talleres y Extracurriculares'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.engineering),
              label: Text('Ingeniería y Agronomía'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.business),
              label: Text('Sociales y Administración'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital),
              label: Text('Salud'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.school),
              label: Text('Iniciales'),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.design_services),
              label: Text('Talleres y Extracurriculares'),
            ),
          ],
          selectedLabelTextStyle:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontSize: 20),
          unselectedLabelTextStyle:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
          groupAlignment: -1,
          minWidth: 56,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html), Unfortunately, current version does not support for alignment, by default it will centered align when the `NavigationRailDestination` has width wider than extended width.

then, based on that behaviour, you can set value of extended Rail SHOULD be wider than the `NavigationRailDestination`

it will align start, see below:

```
NavigationRail(
  selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
  onDestinationSelected: changeDestination,
  extended: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650,
  unselectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
  minExtendedWidth: 300, // you must set this property wider than child
```

by add this `minExtendedWidth: 300,` or wider, we will got this:

[image]

Comment: This is another approach that could be useful to me in certain cases, thank you for the contribution!